# Can I use "mod foo {}" in foo.rs to declare a module and import into main instead of "mod foo" in a rust program?

Tags: rust, module

I have created a new cargo bin project with `src/main.rs` and a separate module in `src/hello.rs`. Here is main.rs:

```rust
mod hello;

use crate::hello::{do_hello};

fn main() {
   do_hello("world");
}
```

and hello.rs:

```rust
pub fn do_hello(text: &str) {
   println!("Hello {text}");
}
```

And this works fine.

Now I want to move the module declaration into the module source hello.rs

```rust
pub mod hello {
    pub fn do_hello(text: &str) {
        println!("Hello {text}");
    }
}
```

However now the compiler can't find the module unless I change main.rs use
statement to `use crate::hello::hello::{do_hello}` like so:

```rust
pub mod hello;

use crate::hello::hello::{do_hello};

fn main() {
   do_hello("world");
}
```

That kind of makes sense but I don't want the to have to say
`use crate::hello::hello` instead of `use crate hello`
so I removed `pub mod hello;` from main.rs and changed the path from `crate::hello::hello` to just `crate::hello`:

```rust
use crate::hello::{do_hello};

fn main() {
   do_hello("world");
}
```

But now it complains that it could not find hello in the crate root.

Is it possible to use the second form of the module declaration, `pub mod hello { ... }`
*and* have the simpler use statement, `use crate::hello` in main.rs?

What would the idiomatic rust way of structuring the code in this case?

Comment: `mod hello;` declares that a module exists and (without a body) tells the compiler to look at the file with that name. Rust doesn't look at any `*.rs` files (besides the root) unless told to by a `mod` declaration. So you *must* have `mod hello;` in `main.rs` in order to compile `hello.rs` and in doing so makes it a module in the crate root.

Comment: *"What would the idiomatic rust way ..."* - what you showed initially looks absolutely normal. Its not clear why you've added a `mod hello { .. }` layer inside `hello.rs` in the first place. If you're coming from another language that has "namespaces" then Rust's modules don't work like that.

Comment: Listing 7-1a of the [chapter 7](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch07-02-defining-modules-to-control-scope-and-privacy.html) of the rust book shows this kind of scoping with `mod hello { ... }`, under what circumstance would you use it? Is that only for library crates?

Comment: @M.Krajnak Those are all in one file. You either use `mod hello;` and then a separate file, or `mod hello { ... }` and put it in the same file (main.rs). You wouldn't do both.

Comment: "rust ... doesn't work like that", I think I'll be hearing a lot of that. :-^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Now I want to move the module declaration into the module source hello.rs

This is simply not possible in Rust. The language uses module declarations to know which files to look for, so without them, it will assume there are no other files. There are [other ways](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.include.html) to include files, but they are far from idiomatic for your situation.

You have two equivalent options: leave it like you originally had it, or move everything into one file.

```rs
mod hello {
    pub fn do_hello(text: &str) {
        println!("Hello {text}");
    }
}

use crate::hello::do_hello;

fn main() {
    do_hello("world");
}
```